# Display information not in a table

Tags: html, css

I have a page that just has a title, header and 3  links.

Is it possible to have them next to each other with a small space in between? I have tried tables but it doesn't create a space, they are too close together. Or if anyone knows a better way to display them please let me know. I just require them to be next to each other.

Eg. Out Of Office--------Leave Application---------Extension List

Just a lot neater and better to look at.

My code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("burg.jpg ");
}
```

```html
<CENTER>
  <h1> Alpine Motors Local Services </h1>
  <HR>
  <table border="0">
    <td>
      <h2><a href="http://172.16.1.9/vacation">*Set Out Of Office*</a></h2 </td>
      <td>
        <h2><a href='leaveform/LeaveForm.php'>Leave Application*</a></h2 </td>
        <td>
          <h2><a href='VW Ext List/index.php'>Extension List Directory*</a>
          </h2>
        </td>
  </table>
  <HR>
</center>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what resources you're using to learn, but I'd recommend finding something else. Your HTML is invalid and you're using elements that no longer exist like `<center>`

Comment: The answer is using floated DIVs with margin and/or padding or just with non-breakable space between them

Answer (score 0):

```
Out Of Office &emsp;&emsp; Leave Application &emsp;&emsp; Extension List
```

This is the easiest way to achieve this with only html, but there are much better ways. Anyways, the output will be as follows

Out Of Office    Leave Application    Extension List

if you want more space between them, simply add more `$emsp;` between words